# Independent Delphi TWebbrowser on IE8 on any OS where any local IE

Tags: delphi, mshtml, twebbrowser

So, it's not easy question ((( it's much time was gone, but I haven't get answer.

The TWebbrowser component working in any OS Windows, but dependent on IE version on this OS. I want decide it by attaching only IE 8 version to my Delphi 7 project and distribute within. But I not understand how do it... One time, I found some application IETester, where does that. There is description of decision: http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HowDoesItWork

Can you help me: how I can do it on the Delphi 7?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I cannot understand the question. Can you try and clarify please.

Comment: TWebBrowser component is just a wrapper for a special COM object interface that is registered with the installation of the Internet Explorer. That is why it is dependent on current installed IE on the system. What IETester does is directly uses the IE libraries to create IE graphical engine independent of the current registered COM interface. So for this you would actually have to create your own component that is able to use those libraries apropirately. ...

Comment: ... But also bare in mind that by doing so you would actually be violating the IE EULA license which states that third party programs may only use IE capabilities through the registered COM interface. Frankly I'm surprised Microsoft hasn't issued any legal action against authors of IETester

Comment: Now if you want to add Web browsing capabilities to your application so that it is not dependant of installed web browsers I suggest you use TChromium (https://github.com/hgourvest/dcef3) component instead.

Comment: Thanks! DCEF3 is good for browser ONLY. But I use IE with EmbedWB component and have got very perfect HTML-editor through rich Microsoft IHTMLDocument2 interface. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752574(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: you can force the component in IE8 only mode via registry (`FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` flag). The only requirement is that the host has IE8 or higher installed.

Comment: There are less invasive ways that registry also, I believe